# Git clone from Bitbucket.org on EC2 server using SSH keys

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, git

We have setup a EC2 build server and would like to use SSH keys to clone the repo.

Steps taken:

```
cd ~/.ssh
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

created config:

```
host bitbucket.org
 HostName bitbucket.org
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/bitbucket_rsa
 User git
```

Loaded public ssh key on bit bucket:

ssh-rsa ...key... ec2_user@ip-censored

When:

```
git clone https://git@bitbucket.org/user/repo.git
```

It ask for password. What should we check or do to see where we are going wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't clone over HTTPS if you want to use public key authentication. You need to modify the url to the SSH one, like this:

```
git clone git@bitbucket.org/user/repo.git
```

or

```
git clone ssh://git@bitbucket.org/user/repo.git
```

should [work for you](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-the-ssh-protocol-with-bitbucket-cloud-221449711.html).

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are doing everything right. The problem may be with ssh parameters that you provide. Here is my configuration that works:

```
Host bitbucket.org
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/bitbucket.pem
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

I think the `StrictHostKeyChecking no` might be the key.